# AngularJS HTTP interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using an interceptor in [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) how can console.log("finished AJAX request") when **any** request has completed?

I have been looking at interceptors and so far have the following but it fires on the start of the request not the end.

```
app.factory('myInterceptor', [function() {
    console.log("finished AJAX request") 

    var myInterceptor = {

    };

    return myInterceptor;
}]);
```

config:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor'); 

etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the console in the response function of the httpInterceptor

```
// register the interceptor as a service
  $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
      // optional method
      'request': function(config) {
        // do something on success
        return config;
      },

      // optional method
     'requestError': function(rejection) {
        // do something on error
        if (canRecover(rejection)) {
          return responseOrNewPromise
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      },



      // optional method
      'response': function(response) {
        // do something on success
        console.log('I am done');
        return response;
      },

      // optional method
     'responseError': function(rejection) {
        // do something on error
        if (canRecover(rejection)) {
          return responseOrNewPromise
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  });

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Over here in the response method I have included the console log function call